# Django_redis lock fails with UnpicklingError

Tags: redis, locking, pickle, django-redis

In one place of my code, I use django_redis to update cache with a lock:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
with cache.lock('hello'):
    # do stuff
```

In another place, I check whether cache is not locked using:

```
if not cache.get('hello'):
    # do other stuff
```

However, when lock is set, `get` call fails with `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'f'.` Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

You can reproduce this behaviour with this snippet:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
with cache.lock('hello'):
    cache.get('hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

it's not very obviously, but as i understand your `lock_key` and `cache_key` must not be the same. for example this code:

```
cache_key = 'hello'
with cache.lock(cache_key):
    cache.get(cache_key)
```

raise `UnpicklingError: invalid load key...`.

In the same time this code:

```
cache_key = 'hello'
lock_key = cache_key + '_lock'
with cache.lock(lock_key):
    cache.get(cache_key)
```

works as you want.